# Metric Space $\mathbb{R}$ question about connected sets and limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

I was wondering if my proof is correct to this question and I have a few other questions after that. I am also using Abbott's theorems

The question is Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is connected and contains more than 1 point. Show that every element of S is a limit point of S.

Here are two theorems I use a lot from the book,
[image]
[image]
Proof. Since S is connected, we know that the statement on the right of Theorem 3.4.6 is True. Suppose $(A \cup B = S) \land (A \cap B = \emptyset)$. This implies that there exists a convergent sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ s.t. $x_n \in A \land x \in B$(I don't think it matters which one you use). This implies that x is a limit point of A since Theorem 3.2.5. Hence, $(\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}+) ((B_r(x)-\{x\})\cap A \neq \emptyset)$. Since $A \subseteq S$, then $(\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}+) ((B_r(x)-\{x\})\cap S \neq \emptyset)$. Therefore x is a limit point for S.

first question, I never explicitly set $x \in S$ rather chosed it based upon Theorem 3.4.6.  I was wondering if that would be an issue.

second question, for theorem 3.4.6, I was wondering what the negation would be for the right-hand side statement.

Comment: Do you know that connected sets in $\mathbb R$ are just intervals?

Comment: So, another way to prove it is because every connected set is an open interval say (a, b). Clearly, $(a, b) \subseteq [a, b]$. But, do you think you can still look at my proof.

Comment: I don't see what you have done to control which point $x$ is. You are supposed to show that every point of $S$ is a limit point. Also make sure you have understood why the conditions (eg contains more than. one point) are there - you haven't explicitly used this.

Comment: Hint: if $x\in S$ is not a limit point of $S$, then $\{x\}$ is  an open and as usual a closed subset of $S$, and $S\setminus\{x\}$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I am not gonna write the whole proof, but I'll do the main part. Let $x \in S$, $S$ be connected, and $S$ contains more than 1 element. Let $A = \{x\}$, which is closed since it has no limit points. Define $B = S - A$, since $S$ contains more than $1$ element $B \neq \emptyset$. Clearly, $A \cup B = S$. Since $S$ is connected either $\overline{A} \cap B \neq \emptyset$ or $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset $. Since $A$ is closed, $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset $ is True. Clearly $x \in \overline{B}$, hence $x$ is a limit point for $B$. Therefore, $x$ is a limit point for $S$. I skipped some small steps but most of the proof is there.